# Opencart Fatal error: Call to a member

Tags: fatal-error

I have a problem, that i cannot solve for a few days. I am trying to migrate from one server to another with opencart 1.5.6.1 and always getting the same error when trying to get to admin, frontpage works well..

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstName() on a non-object in ....../public_html/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 50

**header.php line 50**

```
$this->data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
```

What i've already tried:
 recopy files few times from server to server
 rewrittn admin/config.php and config.php few times

In header php. line 50 changed `$this->customer->getFirstName()` to `$this->customer->getFirstName()`
modified user permissions of config.php...
nothing helps, i still get the same error. 
Please, help ! :)

Comment: Hey could you do a var_dump($this->customer); and tell is the response ? it might be that the customer object doesn't having anything

Comment: Probably some incorrect modification - either yours or from an extension. The admin section doesn't have `$this->customer` but `$this->user`. And the `User` class doesn't have a method `getFirstName()` but `getUserName()`.

Comment: And if it is really an *admin's* `header.php`, then `$this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL')` is also incorrect as there is no such section `Account` in admin... Aren't you trying to *add some fancy stuff* to admin copying over from frontend?

Answer (score -1):

I dont have a clue how to do  var_dump($this->customer) :).
I don't understand why the same web site is working on one server perfectly, but when I copy all the contents of it with filezilla  to another server, edit both config.php files, import database, the frontpage works fine, but admin doesn't and i always get the same error. Maybe I am doing something wrong while moving to another server ?